# Uploading existing labels to SageMaker Ground Truth?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ground-truth

How can I get existing labels into SageMaker Ground Truth? I haven't been able to identify an API to do that, but did I miss an available option or is there a recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to apply existing labels by setting them in the `.manifest` that was used for the list of images to use:

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-data-output.html#sms-output-box

Comment: Can you share your example? What did you put instead of "bounding-box-attribute-name"?

Comment: I figured out that I can put anything I want there